# Type.GetProperties of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range returns empty array

Tags: c#, excel, reflection, interface, getproperties

I want to get a list of properties of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range interface using the following code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
PropertyInfo[] info = typeof(Excel.Range).GetProperties();
```

but the result is an empty array: System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]

Am I missing something?

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is all COM objects. Those can be very weird when it comes to reflection. What are you trying to do that getting the properties of the Range object is the solution to your problem?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was aiming for a tool that would display properties of Excel objects (not specifically Range) and using reflection to get the list of properties seemed the least labor-consumint way. But I've spent quite some time trying to find an answer online why doesn't typeof(Excel.Range).GetProperties() return a list of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS2010, when importing the Office Primary Interop Assemblies (PIAs), the default mechanism for including the type definitions is to embed them as part of the main assembly instead of as separately referenced libraries (Dll). Part of this embedding process is the removal of unreferenced type members from the embedded definition.

In the Solution Explorer, expand the References node and select `Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and then )right-click)->Show Properties.  You should see something like this:

[image: Property View]
Change "Embed Interop Types" to false, verify the "Copy Local" has also been automatically change to True.  Do the same for "Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core" and "Interop.VBIDE".

Now when you reflect the managed wrapper interop types, you will get the complete type definition.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have "Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core" and "Interop.VBIDE" in References. I changed "Office.dll" (...\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Office.dll) Embed to false and it is working now!